# JavaScript in AJAX code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form with a submit button like this:

```
<input name="sub" type="submit" value=" " id="sub" class="sub" style="cursor:pointer;" title=""/>
```

The data is sent to a ajax.php script via POST method. The listing is here:

```
<?php
include("../scripts/lib.php");
if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
echo "<script>
if (parent.document.getElementById('sub').className=='sub') {
parent.document.getElementById('sub').style.display='none';
parent.document.getElementById('loader').src='../../images/ajax-loader.gif';
    setTimeout(function() { 
        parent.document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').style.display='block';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').className = 'subOK';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').title = '1';
    }, 1000);
} else if (parent.document.getElementById('sub').className=='subOK') {
parent.document.getElementById('sub').style.display='none';
parent.document.getElementById('loader').src='../../images/ajax-loader.gif';
    setTimeout(function() { 
        parent.document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').style.display='block';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').className = 'sub';
        parent.document.getElementById('sub').title = '2';
    }, 1000);
}
</script>";
exit;
}
?>
```

Everything works just fine for me, but only there is a tyny problem. Once the page is loaded you can press the submit button and see ajax-loader.gif showing only once. **How do I alter the code so that it works all the time?**

Comment: why, for the love of god, do you have dom manipulation code being returned by php?

Comment: You should DOM manipulation use in `success` function ajax's callback, in ajax result you should return data in json : `{className:'subOk',title:'1'}` or `{className:'sub',title:'2'}`